# Running SQL Server 2012 in Container in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker

At work we load data into a SQL Server 2012 database, and create `.bak` files that are exported. Yes that is correct, due to compatibility issues, we need to use SQL Server 2012.

This process, which is probably running for 3-4 hours per day, is currently running on an on-premise machine, but we want to move it to Azure.

However, SQL databases in Azure are v2017+, but I have read that it's possible to [run SQL Sever 2012 in a Docker container](https://anushibin.wordpress.com/2020/03/25/microsoft-sql-server-2012-on-docker). Before I invest a lot of time into this idea, has any one tried to host an old SQL Server version in a Docker container in Azure?

Comment: Don't go there. Your best bet is a VM. SQL 2012 can only run in Windows containers and MS has suspended their SQL Server Windows container program. Although you can run SQL 2012 in containers with a custom image, it is an entirely unsupported and lonely path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, use a VM. Microsoft maintain VM images all the way back to 2008 plus you can integrate backup and automatic updates to the OS and SQL. Images are listed here and you can pay as you go or bring your own license:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-on-azure-vm-iaas-what-is-overview

In the pay as you go model you can shutdown the VM (i.e. the VM itself not just the OS) and you won’t get charged for the VM or the SQL license. You will still get charged for storage. See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/pricing-guidance#pay-per-usage